# Where to stop on the trans-siberian railway?

Tags: russia, train-stations, trans-siberian

The destination is Beijing.

I will take the trip at the end of November. It is cold then.

I think I will bypass Mongolia because of the visa problem.

So any good place to stop? One choice is Irkutsk. Another one?

Comment: If you didn't see the passion bearers memorial in Yekaterinburg, it's a must; bordering on a spiritual experience.  Also, if you can get in to Krasnoyarsk before it closes, you may be among the last visitors in this century to do so.

Comment: @GayotFow: In what sense is Krasnoyarsk going to close?  I didn't find any information about this.

Comment: @NateEldredge, it means flat-out *closed*,  It becomes a non-place. Disappears.  Nobody gets in without a clearance, not even Russians.  You can read the Wiki entry for [Seversk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seversk) (where they make their nuclear weapons) and get an idea.

Comment: @GayotFow: But I didn't find any sources suggesting this is going to happen to the city of Krasnoyarsk, or saying why.  Can you point me to any? (Or did you mean the entire krai?  Or some other city in the vicinity?  It seems there are already other closed cities around there, like [Zheleznogorsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zheleznogorsk,_Krasnoyarsk_Krai), which was formerly code-named "Krasnoyarsk-26" - could this be the root of some confusion?)

Comment: @NateEldredge, first the city, then the entire krai. I got it from Krasnoyarsk residents in a Russian speaking forum I monitor. The government is upgrading the city to be a hyper-modern infrastructure, are you hoping to be the last visitor? Or have other interest?

Comment: @GayotFow: No, I'm merely curious and a bit skeptical.

Comment: @NateEldredge, you can take this up in chat if I can help further.  In the meantime, CASCC :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27024/discussion-between-nate-eldredge-and-gayot-fow).

Comment: On my previous trip I found the Mongolian visa to be the easiest one to obtain that was not a visa on arrival. I got mine in Hohhot, China while I waited.